# How do I create a Random Border Radius?

Tags: function, styles

In the Javascript portion of The Complete Web Developer Course on Udemy, Rob (the teacher) makes a div randomly become either a circle or square based on a simple if-then statement. But how would I create a square with a completely random border radius?

function getRadius() {

```
    var radius=Math.random();
    radius = radius * 100;
}
```

function makeBox() {

```
    var time=Math.random();
    time=time*2000;

    setTimeout(function() {

        document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius="50px";

        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor=getRandomColor();

        document.getElementById("box").style.display="block";
        createdTime=Date.now();
    }, time);
}
```

The program works when I have just have an integer with px after like in the example, but I can't seem to figure out how to change the 50 to the function getRadius, if that makes sense. Nothing appears with

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div id="box" onclick="change();">
<p>click me</p>
<div>
```

css:

```
#box{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

js:

```
function change(){
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    box.style.borderRadius= num+'px';
};
```